# Myget and VSTS integration

Tags: azure-devops, myget

I'm using VSO to host and build my code. I also followed these steps [MyGet with Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/services/myget) to have the packages available as myget feed but someone the feeds are always empty. I only have the 'Nuget Package' build step but it seems to me that I will also need the 'Nuget Publisher' is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to add Nuget Publisher step/task to publish package, need to make sure the package is in the build drop (Publish Build Artifacts)

Simple steps:

1. Create a new build definition
2. (Optional) Add NuGet Installer
3. Add Visual Studio Build step/task to build your solution/project
4. Add NuGet Packager step/task (Path to csproj: ***.csproj; Package Folder: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory))
5. Add Publish Build Artifacts (Path to Publish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory); Artifact Name: drop; Artifact Type: Server)
6. Save build definition
7. Open feed of your myget
8. Click Package sources
9. Click Add package source >Visual Studio Team Services Build Definition. (refer to [Deploy a package built on Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/services/myget#deploy-a-package-built-on-visual-studio-team-services))
10. Queue previous build on VSTS
11. Wait some minutes and check package in myget.

Comment: I tried it and it wasn't working so I decided to and the Publish task so push the packages to myget using a generic service and got it all working. Thanks.

Comment: @Marco What's detail of build log? On the other hand, you can post an answer with your solution and accept it as answer.

Comment: @starin-MSFT the build server on VSO was working properly, it seems the problem was related with myget. I waited around 10 min but the packages never made it to myget, so I tried the other way, I did what I wrote above and got it working.

Comment: @Marco What're steps of your build definition? Can you provide the build log? On the other hand, since you have solved the issue, can you post an answer and accept it as answer?